# Awk seems to be confused what $1 is

Tags: awk

I use awk a fair bit for parsing logs; I have never seen anything like this:
I have six file containing a number of lines; I want the ones containing "100", and to choose which columns to print

```
me:~/tmp> grep 100 *.dl.tst
```

outputs what I expect:

```
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  6376k      0  0:00:22  0:00:22 --:--:-- 6539k
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  6677k      0  0:00:21  0:00:21 --:--:-- 6579k
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  6022k      0  0:00:23  0:00:23 --:--:-- 6093k
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  13.9M      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:-- 14.3M
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  14.3M      0  0:00:09  0:00:09 --:--:-- 14.7M
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  13.2M      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:-- 13.3M
```

as does:

```
me:~/tmp> grep 100 *.dl.tst|awk '{print$0}'
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  6376k      0  0:00:22  0:00:22 --:--:-- 6539k
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  6677k      0  0:00:21  0:00:21 --:--:-- 6579k
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  6022k      0  0:00:23  0:00:23 --:--:-- 6093k
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  13.9M      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:-- 14.3M
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  14.3M      0  0:00:09  0:00:09 --:--:-- 14.7M
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  13.2M      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:-- 13.3M
```

Why then does `$1` become the file name:

```
me:~/tmp> grep 100 *.dl.tst|awk '{print$1}'
shpr002.20201124_141036.dl.tst:
shpr003.20201124_141036.dl.tst:
shpr004.20201124_141036.dl.tst:
hipr002.20201124_141036.dl.tst:
hipr003.20201124_141036.dl.tst:
hipr004.20201124_141036.dl.tst:
```

And `$2`:

```
me:~/tmp> grep 100 *.dl.tst|awk '{print$2}'
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I logged out and back in in case my shell (bash) was screwed up; no change... what am I doing wrong?

Output from `grep 100 *.dl.tst | awk '{print$1}' | head -n1 | od -c`
(some of the alpha characters have been substituted by `x`; the list above had been edited/obfuscated)

```
0000000   x  s   h   p   r   0   0   2   x   x   x  .   x   x   x   .
0000020   x   x   x   x   .   c   o   m   .   2   0   2   0   -   1   1
0000040   -   2   4   _   1   4   1   0   3   6   .   d   l   .   t   s
0000060   t   :  \r  \n
0000064
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `grep 100 *.dl.tst | awk '{print$1}' | head -n1 | od -c`.  The file name is normal, that's grep adding the file name to the output, but it should also be there when you `print $0`. I'm thinking you might have some non-printing characters which is why I asked for that output.

Comment: You're running this on Windows or Linux/UNIX or Mac?

Comment: Linux.
Output from "grep 100 *.dl.tst | awk '{print$1}' | head -n1 | od -c"
(some of the alpha characters have been substituted by "x"; the list above had been edited/obfuscated)
```
0000000   x  s   h   p   r   0   0   2   x   x   x  .   x   x   x   .
0000020   x   x   x   x   .   c   o   m   .   2   0   2   0   -   1   1
0000040   -   2   4   _   1   4   1   0   3   6   .   d   l   .   t   s
0000060   t   :  \r  \n
0000064
```

Comment: I couldn't resist: You're saying that awk doesn't know the value of $1

Comment: @Ross, I say a lot things that are less than 100% accurate; I know/knew it me that was confused as to what was going on, I was just trying to convey my limited understanding of the issue.

Comment: @Iain, I think he meant that just as a pun. Awk not knowing the value of one dollar.

Comment: @Iain Sorry if my humor was too obscure .. there's an old catchphrase "know the value of a dollar" (as ikkachu mentioned). It's often a criticism from a parent to a spendthrift child :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those files contain the output from `curl` downloading files, and `curl` updates its progress information during downloads by outputting a carriage return (commonly represented as `\r`, the escape used to produce it in a number of contexts), which causes the cursor to return to the start of the line.

When you run `grep 100 *.dl.tst`, each line that’s output starts with the file name, but that’s followed by multiple updates which return the cursor to the start of the line, so you don’t see the file name — it’s overwritten by subsequent output. In more detail, the output looks like

```
shpr002.20201124_141036.dl.tst:
```

followed by a carriage return, followed by the first progress output from `curl`,

```
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

followed by a carriage return, etc., until the percentage reaches 100. Because all this is only separated by carriage returns, not line feeds, it counts as a single line, and `grep` matches that in its entirety.

The same effect explains the output of `grep 100 *.dl.tst|awk '{print$0}'`.

When you ask AWK to output `$1`, it outputs the first field, and now you can see it: it contains the file name, a colon, a carriage return, and that’s it — the start of `curl`’s output then starts with a space (to leave room for the percentage count), which is a field separator. When you ask it to output `$2`, it outputs the second field, which is the first percentage count, `0`:

```
shpr002.20201124_141036.dl.tst:\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

<--          Field 1          -->  !     !    !     !  ...
                                   $2    $3   $4    $5 ...
```

Comment: They are indeed output from curl, but if I cat one, all I get is the headers and final, 100%, output:
`% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  6022k      0  0:00:23  0:00:23 --:--:-- 6093k`
Where's the rest of it?

Comment: It’s overwritten, every time the cursor returns to the start of the line. Open the files with `less` to see what’s going on; it will show the carriage returns as `^M`.

Comment: In the absence of a fix (as opposed to a diagnosis: `awk '{ sub ("^.*\r", ""); print; }'`

Comment: "_Where's the rest of it?" You could pass a log-file through `tr '\r' '\n'` to "see the rest of it".

Answer (score 4):

Working on [Stephen's description of the issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/621340/170373), a simple way to make the output easier to process would be just translate all the carriage returns into newlines, leaving you with curl's progress report as a bunch of individual lines, which you can then use `awk` on:

```
$ for f in *.dl; do < "$f" tr '\r' '\n' | awk '$1 == "100" {print $0}' ; done
100  720k  100  720k    0     0  22.5M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 22.7M
100 23.6M  100 23.6M    0     0   372M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  369M
```

(Though, if curl rounds the percentage it prints to nearest integer instead of down, huge files might show multiple lines with `100` in the first column.)

On the other hand, if it's known that the files contain nothing but the output from curl, then we might as well just pick the last line instead of looking at the contents:

```
$ for f in *.dl; do < "$f" tr '\r' '\n' | tail -n1  ; done
100  720k  100  720k    0     0  22.5M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 22.7M
100 23.6M  100 23.6M    0     0   372M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  369M
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to using `sed -n '$p'` over `tail -n 1`?  (``tail`` is probably faster if the input is a file; maybe not if it’s a pipe.)

Comment: @Scott, no, other than the fact that I managed to completely forget about `tail` when writing that. Thanks for the reminder. Yes, an optimized implementation of `tail` will definitely be much faster on a (large) file, and even from a pipe, `tail` was 2-3 times faster than `sed` on my Debian. Given a large enough input that the difference is visible, that is.